# Adding Advanced Services to SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (x86, Version 10.0.2531). Today, I needed to use full-text index option. This option can be seen by right clicking a table name in object explorer. My mentioned version of SQL Server just show the option "Full-Text Index" in the menu, but it cannot be clicked upon, because it is disabled. I was told some where that i should download and install "SQL Server 2008 Express with Advance Services" which allows full-text search. I have following questions to ask.

1. Can I download the Advanced Services packages to my current version of SQL Server so that full-text index will be available on my current version of SQL Server?
2. Can I install SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services in such a way that my databases and tables in my current version of SQL Server will not be deleted? Or, is there any way to upgrade my current version of SQL Server to SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services?

Comment: **For safety and peace of mind**: first stop the existing SQL Server Express service and backup all your database files. But after that : just install the new package with the **Advanced** services - that should be fine, no issues, shouldn't delete any of your database files.

Comment: your defined precautions seem to be useful. thank you.